# DB2 query not returning rows with NULL column values

Tags: db2

I am writing DB2 query where I am trying to return all rows including NULL except when ID is not equal to 100.

However, running below query I am getting all desired rows except when `U4156_GRPDC_CLM_FLDR_EXTREF` is `NULL`. Is there I am missing something here? Please help.

```
SELECT 
    OBJECT_ID, VERSION_STATUS, OBJECT_CLASS_ID, SECURITY_ID, 
    SECURITY_FOLDER_ID, RECOVERY_ITEM_ID, U4156_GRPDC_CLM_FLDR_EXTREF, 
    U9C48_CMACMCASEIDENTIFIER, U3E88_GRPDC_COMM_STTS
FROM
    OSDBUSR.DOCVERSION T0 
WHERE  
    U4156_GRPDC_CLM_FLDR_EXTREF <> 1000
```

Comment: add "or U4156_GRPDC_CLM_FLDR_EXTREF is null" and remeber NULL can not be compared to anything and NULL = NULL is false

Answer (score 2):

As Micheal says `NULL = NULL` is false, and counter-intuitively `NULL <> NULL` is also false. For your query `NULL <> 1000` is also false, so rows with a `NULL` in column U4156_GRPDC_CLM_FLDR_EXTREF won't match your predicate and will be filtered out. You can blame Codd if you wish, but that is just the ways NULLs work in SQL.

So to get the result you want you will need the following

```
SELECT 
    OBJECT_ID, VERSION_STATUS, OBJECT_CLASS_ID, SECURITY_ID, 
    SECURITY_FOLDER_ID, RECOVERY_ITEM_ID, U4156_GRPDC_CLM_FLDR_EXTREF, 
    U9C48_CMACMCASEIDENTIFIER, U3E88_GRPDC_COMM_STTS
FROM
    OSDBUSR.DOCVERSION T0 
WHERE  
    U4156_GRPDC_CLM_FLDR_EXTREF <> 1000
OR  U4156_GRPDC_CLM_FLDR_EXTREF IS NULL
```